useState set method not changed its value
all. I am trying to use isDraging to update the status of an icon; however, I found the setDragging method is not working, the isDraging always return false, I don't know where goes wrong. How can I fix this issue. If there is anything unclear, please let me know. Thanks in advance.
  const [isDragging, setIsDragging] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const onMouseMove = (moveEvent: MouseEvent) => {
    if (!isDragging || !videoContainerRef.current) return;
    setPosition({
      x: `${moveEvent.clientX - offsetX}px`,
      y: `${moveEvent.clientY - offsetY}px`,
    });
  };

  const onMouseUp = () => {
    setIsDragging(false);
    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
    document.removeEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp);
  };

  // Handle Video Dragging
  const handleMouseDown = (e: React.MouseEvent) => {
    if (!videoContainerRef.current) return
    setIsDragging(true);
    
    offsetX = e.clientX - (videoContainerRef.current?.offsetLeft! || 0);
    offsetY = e.clientY - (videoContainerRef.current?.offsetTop! || 0);
    
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp);
  }
  return (
    <div 
    ref={videoContainerRef}
    role='presentation'
    onMouseDown={handleMouseDown}
    style={{
      position: 'fixed',
      top: `${position.y}`,
      left: `${position.x}`,
      width: `${size.width}px`,
      height: `${size.height}px`,
      cursor: isDragging ? 'grabbing' : 'grab',
      transform: `translate(${position.x}, ${position.y})`,
      transition: 'transform 0.1s ease-out', // Add smooth transition to dragging
    }}>
....
</div>


It's also similar to React, can't access updated value of state variable inside function passed to setInterval() in useEffect() in that you're making the same mistake of capturing the stale value in your closure function bound to the event listeners
